# D3 v4 enter() transition fails to draw circle on canvas on first invocation

Tags: d3.js

I'm having trouble debugging why in my attempt to re-write this [block](http://bl.ocks.org/JMStewart/43ec6ba5df865181a66d) using d3 v4, the circles do not appear until drawWithData is called a second time. You can click on 'Add' or 'Draw' to see the effects.

Other than changing the force object to the v4 simulation object, the way the canvas is drawn and DOM objects transitions should be the same.

A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u3ntL9b9/2/) for those who want to take a look. The following is the contents of function drawWithData(data, simulation):

```
circles = container.selectAll('circle')
                   .data(data);

// Insertion animation.
newCircles = circles.enter()
                    .append('circle')
                    .attr("id", function(d, i){ return d.id; })
                    .attr('r', 0)
                    .attr('alpha', 1)
                    ;

circles.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr('r', function(d){
            return d.r;
        });

// Deletion animation
dyingCircles = circles.exit();
dyingCircles.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .attr('r', 0)
            .attr('alpha', 0)
            .remove();

simulation.on('tick', function() {
    var renderStart = new Date();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(70, 130, 180)";
    context.beginPath();

    circles.each(function(d) {
        context.moveTo(d.x, d.y);
        var radius = d3.select(this).attr('r'); // because d.r contains the final value
        context.arc(d.x, d.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    });

    dyingCircles.each(function(d) {
        context.moveTo(d.x, d.y);
        var alpha = d3.select(this).attr('alpha');
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(70, 130, 180, "+alpha+")";
        var radius = d3.select(this).attr('r'); // because d.r contains the final value
        context.arc(d.x, d.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    });

    context.fill();

    time += (new Date() - renderStart);
    ticks++;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed:

```
circles.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr('r', function(d){
            return d.r;
        });
```

to:

```
newCircles.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr('r', function(d){
            return d.r;
        });
```

and the Draw button works on the first click. As below when you transition the dyingCircles, you want to do the same to the newCircles.

Comment: you missed one other spot where he's still referencing `circles` instead of `newCircles` (line 92), but this is on the right track.

Comment: Thanks Bruce and Dan! The transition does seem to need to be applied to the enter or exit selection ... I'm still learning the general update flow of d3. I wonder how the original sample worked in the first place. I also had to apply the draw function to all 3 selections (circles, newCircles and dyingCircles). The updated jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/u3ntL9b9/26/